# Filter Google Map Markers with Checkboxes and Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: google-maps, filtering, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields to add Google Map markers in WordPress. I have a set of filters which categorize the markers. My goal is to only show the map markers of the checked filters. I have found several examples on Stack Overflow, but most of these examples are using json data or static arrays. My JS skills aren't at a level where I can translate this to my situation.

Here is the HTML for the filters that will be above the map:

```
<article class="map-filters">
    <div class="map-filters__inner">
        <ul class="map-filters__wrap">
            <li><label for="category1"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="category1" id="category1" checked>Category 1</label></li>
            <li><label for="category2"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="category2" id="category2" checked>Category 2</label></li>
            <li><label for="category3"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="category3" id="category3" checked>Category 3</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</article>
```

Here is the HTML for the map itself. Again, I am using ACF repeater fields to dynamically add map markers, but I am providing the static HTML for the purposes of this example:

```
<article id="js-community-map" class="community-map">
    <div class="marker" data-category="category1"  data-icon="category1.png" data-lat="35.9491598" data-lng="-115.1354093">Marker Content</div> 
    <div class="marker" data-category="category2"  data-icon="category2.png" data-lat="35.9320515" data-lng="-115.1236344">Marker Content</div> 
    <div class="marker" data-category="category3"  data-icon="category2.png" data-lat="35.9327263" data-lng="-115.1246636">Marker Content</div> 
</article>
```

Lastly, is the js. You will see that it is slightly different from the typical Google Maps JS because of the use of Advanced Custom Fields, but should be very similar. The problem I am having is that I don't know where to add the filtering functionality within this code. It's also possible that my filtering code is incorrect. I have tried adding the filtering in several places including the new_map function, but nothing seems to work. It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me work through this.

```
(function($) {

    // New Map  
    // This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
    function new_map( $el ) {

        // var
        var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

        // args
        var args = {
            zoom        : 16,
            center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // create map               
        var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

        // add a markers reference
        map.markers = [];

        // add markers
        $markers.each(function(){
            add_marker( $(this), map );
        });

        // center map
        center_map( map );

       // return
       return map;
    }

    // Add Marker
    function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

        // vars
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
        var category = $marker.data('category'); // Get category name from data

        // create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position    : latlng,
            map         : map,
            category    : category, // store category as property of marker
            icon        : iconUrl.image + $marker.attr('data-icon') // Custom icon from data attribute
        });

        // add to array
        map.markers.push( marker );

        // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
        if( $marker.html() ) {

            // create info window
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content     : $marker.html()
            });

            // show info window when marker is clicked
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(15);
                infowindow.open( map, marker );
            });
        }
    }

    // Center Map   
    function center_map( map ) {

        // vars
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        // loop through all markers and create bounds
        $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
            bounds.extend( latlng );
        });

        // only 1 marker?
        if( map.markers.length == 1 ) {

            // set center of map
            map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
            map.setZoom( 16 );

        } else {

            // fit to bounds
            map.fitBounds( bounds );

        }
    }

    // Document Ready    
    // global var
    var map = null;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#js-community-map').each(function(){

            // create map
            map = new_map( $(this) );

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the filtering functionality that I am trying to use. Please let me know if I need to make changes to this code. Also, if you could help me place this in the JS above it would be very helpful.

```
$(document).on('click', '.map-filters__wrap label', function(){
    $.each(map.markers, function(i, marker) {
        if(marker.category == category) {
            marker.visible = true;
        } else {
            marker.visible = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out on my own for anyone who needs to do filtering with ACF Google Maps!

Here is the updated JS with the filters working:

```
(function($) {

    // New Map   
    // This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
    function new_map( $el ) {

        // var
        var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

        // vars
        var args = {
            zoom        : 16,
            center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // create map               
        var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
        // add a markers reference
        map.markers = [];

        // add markers
        $markers.each(function(){
            add_marker( $(this), map );
        });

        // Filter Markers
        $('.map-filters__wrap').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function ( {
            filter = $(this);
            filterValue = filter.val();
            if(filter.is(':checked')) {
                map.markers.forEach(function(element) {
                    if(element.category == filterValue) {
                        element.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                map.markers.forEach(function(element) {
                    if(element.category == filterValue) {
                        element.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // center map
        center_map( map );

        // return
        return map;
    }


    // Add Marker 
    function add_marker( $marker, map ) {
        // var
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
        var category = $marker.data('category'); // Get category name from data

        // create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position    : latlng,
            draggable   : true, // set marker to draggable to hide duplicates
            crossOnDrag : false, // hide cross icon on drag event
            map         : map,
            category    : category, // store category as property of marker
            icon        : iconUrl.image + $marker.attr('data-icon') // Custom icon from data attribute
        });

        // add to array
        map.markers.push( marker );

        // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
        if( $marker.html() ) {

            // create info window
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content     : $marker.html()
            });

            // show info window when marker is clicked
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open( map, marker );
            });
        }
    }
    // Center Map   
    function center_map( map ) {

        // vars
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        // loop through all markers and create bounds
        $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
            bounds.extend( latlng );
        });

        // only 1 marker?
        if( map.markers.length == 1 ) {

            // set center of map
            map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
            map.setZoom( 16 );
        } else {

            // fit to bounds
            map.fitBounds( bounds );

        }
    }

    // Document Ready  
    // global var
    var map = null;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#js-community-map').each(function(){
            // create map
            map = new_map( $(this) );
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the example, I am new to it and it was very helpful!

Just a small observation that can make some other newbies a bit confuse, there is a really small syntax error here:

**Filter Markers**

```
$('.map-filters__wrap').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function ( {
```

There is a `)` missing there, it should be:

**Filter Markers**

```
$('.map-filters__wrap').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
```

Comment: This is very helpful information to have in the answer itself.  I recommend you edit the answer to fix the syntax error that way it's always there for people in the future to see without having to scroll through all the answers.